# How replace OnMouseDown in Unity's new input system?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity has a new inputsystem where the old `OnMouseDown() {}` no longer works.

In the [migration guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.9/manual/Migration.html) they mention replacing this with `Mouse.current.leftButton.isPressed`.
And in other forum posts they mention using an `InputAction`.
The problem is that these options detect mouse clicks *anywhere* in the scene, instead of just on the object:

```
public InputAction clickAction;

void Awake() {
      clickAction.performed += ctx => OnClickedTest();
}

void OnClickedTest(){
      Debug.Log("You clicked anywhere on the screen!");
}

// this doesn't work anymore in the new system
void OnMouseDown(){
      Debug.Log("You clicked on this specific object!");
}
```

How can I detect mouse clicks *on a specific gameObject* with the new input system in Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have a an `EventSystem` with an `InputSystemUIInputModule` in the scene and a `PhysicsRaycaster` or `Physics2DRaycaster` on your `Camera`, and then use the `IPointerClickHandler` interface on the object with a collider on itself or its children:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {
    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log ("clicked");
    }
 }
```

Comment: But it's not the new Input system. EventSystems is from the Unity UI package.

Comment: What is "the object"? I need to be able to detect whether a click was clicked anywhere on the screen. I'm implementing a context menu which appears next to the user's cursor (like when you right click in Windows or Mac). If they click anywhere, it should disappear. 

I could make "the object" be a giant invisible button that appears right behind the menu. But consider this: Now the other UI elements won't get the click event. If the user wanted to click one of those while the menu was active, it won't work for that click.

Comment: @Peyotle - `InputSystemUIInputModule` is in fact from the new Input System. Yes, the `EventSystem` is from the UI package, as is `PhysicsRaycaster`: the UI package has the Unity-supplied solution for what Kolja is doing manually. The new Input System is a replacement for `UnityEngine.Input`, not for the UI package.

@pete - This is what the original question already had solved with `Mouse.current.leftButton.isPressed` - the question was in fact about clicking an object.

Answer (score 12):

With this code somewhere in your scene:

```csharp
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseClicks : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera gameCamera; 
    private InputAction click;

    void Awake() 
    {
        click = new InputAction(binding: "<Mouse>/leftButton");
        click.performed += ctx => {
            RaycastHit hit; 
            Vector3 coor = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
            if (Physics.Raycast(gameCamera.ScreenPointToRay(coor), out hit)) 
            {
                hit.collider.GetComponent<IClickable>()?.OnClick();
            }
        };
        click.Enable();
    }
}
```

You can add an `IClickable` Interface to all GameObjects that want to respond to clicks:

```csharp
public interface IClickable
{
    void OnClick();
}
```

and

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickableObject : MonoBehaviour, IClickable
{
    public void OnClick() 
    {
        Debug.Log("somebody clicked me");
    }
}
```

Comment: That still requires an object. What if you need to detect whether a click was clicked anywhere on the screen? Say you have a context menu appearing right next to the cursor, which pops up when a user clicks on something. Seems like an incredibly common and trivial thing to do in a game. But now there is no way to make it disappear if the user clicks anywhere on the screen. And if we make the hack of having a giant invisible button behind the menu, that means the other UI elements won't be clickable while the menu is active.

Comment: Very useful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use

`Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame`

With a Raycast and a object with a collider in world space it would look like this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.transform.name == "TargetObjName")
        {
print("PointerOnObj");
            if (Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame)
            {
                print("clicked");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems the answer lies in the context type:

```
InputAction.CallbackContext
```

The way I did it was using the context "canceled" property. When it is false, that means the mouse press just occurred. When it is true, that means the mouse press has been caneceled (and then indicating a OnMouseUp event).

It seems it has a few properties to make this fit other use cases, such as a duration indicating how long the button was down etc.